# AutoMapping: Dereference of a possibly null reference? Null-conditional operator doesn't work with AutoMapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper for class `A` and `B`. The project is a .Net core project with `<Nullable>enabled</Nullable>`.

```
public class A 
{
    public ClassX? X { get; set; } // ClassX is a custom class with the property of Value.
    //.... 
}

public class B 
{
    public string? X { get; set; } 
   // ....
}
```

In the following mapping code

```
public void Mapping(Profile profile)
{
    // ....

    _ = profile?.CreateMap<A, B>()
        .ForMember(d => d.X, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.X.Value)); // warning on s.X
}
```

it has the following warning on `s.X`:

> Warning   CS8602  Dereference of a possibly null reference.

How to get rid of the warning without using `#pragma warning disable CS8602`?

I tried to change `o.MapFrom(s => s.X.Value)` to `o.MapFrom(s => s.X?.Value)` using Null-conditional. But it got the following **error** on `s.X?.Value`.

> Error CS8072 An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Comment: I have removed CS8602 , this warning its terrible even specific guards ( eg Guard/Ensure  fail early ) are ignored and than a ton of conditionals are needed because it cant tell.  

It then result in contaminated / harder to read code and people wasting time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `MapFrom` accepts an `Expression<>` and not a `Func<>`, you cannot use the Null-conditional operator. This is not a limitation of AutoMapper, it is a limitation of the expression trees in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace and of the C# compiler.

However, you can use a ternary operator:

```
_ = profile?.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(d => d.X, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.X == null ? null : s.X.Value));
```

According to your declaration, the property `X` is nullable. Therefore, you must ensure that it will not be dereferenced if it is null.

(According to @Attersson) If you want to assign a different value in the null case, you can use the null-coalescing operator in conjunction with the ternary operator:

```cs
(s.X == null ? someDefaultValue : s.X.Value)

// e.g for string
(s.Text == null ? String.Empty : s.Text)
```

Comment: (and eventually specify the value in case of null with ??)

Comment: This will get the error of Severity `Error CS8072 An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.`

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if Automapper had been updated to allow that operator in `MapFrom` expressions.  The coalescing operators don't work within `MapFrom`, at least in older versions of Automapper.

Comment: IIRC, you can use the coalescing operators with Automappers `Resolve...` methods, but not the `Map...` methods.

Comment: @ca9163d9: Oaky, I see. Obviously `MapFrom` has an `Expression<something>` parameter. Epression trees cannot express null-conditionals; however they access ternary expressions. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Expression tree seems have a lot of constraints - no `?.`, no pattern matching, etc.